# How to fix password problem with CockroachDB and Spring-Boot

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, liquibase, cockroachdb

I have a problem with spring-boot and cockroachDB. On my local machine runs cockraochDB and spring-boot. As soon as spring boot starts , i'm getting an exception. Cockroach runs in insecure mode.

application.yaml:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql:localhost:26257/mydb?sslmode=disable
    username: myuser
    password: 
  jpa:
      properties:
         hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect
      show-sql: true
      database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect
      hibernate:
         ddl-auto: create
```

pom.xml section:

```
[...]
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
[...]
```

I created two users. One with no password and one with a password in database "mydb" on cockroachDB. Both are not working. Append "?sslmode=disable" to the url in spring.datasource.url also not working.

Exception without password:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The server requested password-based authentication, but no password was provided.
```

Exception with password:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "myuser"
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Check with database url :- jdbc:postgresql://localhost:26257/mydb?sslmode=disable

Comment: Haha thanks @GovindParashar. I was blind ;) It works perfect :)

Comment: That's great I'll post as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use`://` after postgressql in your datasource url.

Your datasource url should be

```
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:26257/mydb?sslmode=disable
```